# Can I show the Facebook Activity Log for a Page on an external site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss, facebook-c#-sdk, feed

A Facebook Page has an RSS feed. This feed appears to only show the users' activity on the page.

Furthermore, there's the Like Box. But the Like Box appears to only show the Page's own comments, and none of the users' activities.

Finally there's the Activity Log. This appears to combine the two above, but there does not seem to be a feed for this. A feed or plugin similar to the entries in the Activity Log would be exactly what the customer is looking for.

Is there any way to display the Page Activity Log entries on an external website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Activity log is private and there's no API or social plgin to retrieve or display it elsewhere

Comment: I mean, can I display a similar feed somehow? A mix of Page posts and user posts on the Page?

Comment: No, you'd have to do this yourself by retrieving the posts from the API and redisplaying them